# Zero values in the array in the method paint

Tags: java, arrays, swing, awt, paint

I would like to make a graphical representation of the audio signal.
I have a problem with entering data array to the method paint (Graphics g).
Data entered in the method setData(int intValue) works fine.
But if I want to print a data array in the method paint() I have zero values. 
Why?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyPlotter extends JPanel{
    int width = 320;
    int height = 130;
    int frameSize;
    int[] data;

public MyPlotter(int fSize){
    setSize(width,height);      
    setPreferredSize(this.getSize());
    this.frameSize = fSize;
    data = new int[fSize+1];
} 


public void setData(int[] intValue){
    data = intValue;

// this works fine:
        for (int i=0; i<440; i++)
            System.out.println("setData "+data[i]);

    repaint();
}

public void paint (Graphics g){ 

   // some code:
   // g.drawLine(...)
   // g.setColor(...)
   // etc...    

 for (int i = 0; i< frameSize-1;i++)
    { 
     //ZERO values:
     System.out.println("paint() "+(data[i]));

     // g.drawline(...);
    }
 }
 }
```

Edit:

Array Data is entered from MyPanel.class

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private MyPlotter plotter;

    public MyPanel(){
      setSize(320,210);
      plotter = new MyPlotter(440);
      add(this.plotter,0);
    }

    public void setData(int[] data){
      plotter.setData(data);  
    }   
}
```

Comment: When do you call `setData()`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - `public void paint (Graphics g){` should be `public void paintComponent (Graphics g){` for custom painting in a `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that possibly the "repaint()" method you called modifies the original array "intValue"

The assignment you have made `data = intValue;` only makes "data[]" a reference of your original array so as repaint is called seems like the data is reset or the reference is lost.If you want to copy the array you can do any of the following if a & b are two arrays:

```
b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
```

0r

```
b = new int[a.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, b.length);
```

or

```
b = (int[]) a.clone();
```

or

```
int b[] = new int[a.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            b[i] = a[i];
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, these solutions do not fix the problem.

Comment: Hey Do you need data to be a class variable that is common to every instance of the class then you have to make the variable static int[] data; so that different instances of the same class do not have new copies of data variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = intValue;
```

Here you are psssing reference of intValue to data. If you change data intValue array also get changed.

Try this :

```
data = System.arraycopy( intValue, 0, data, 0, intValue.length);
```

Instead of :

```
data = intValue;
```

Comment: I introduce the array data from the outside. I'd like the same data in the paint method.

Comment: I tried these  but I get an error: "inconvertible types required: int found: void"

Comment: @auroris Try data = Arrays.copyOf(intValue, intValue.length);

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK. The problem is in the main method. Ensure you have  added only one plotter to the panel.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    int[] mass =  new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    JFrame frame =  new JFrame();
    MyPanel mp = new MyPanel();
    frame.add(mp);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);         
    mp.setData(mass);         
    frame.setVisible(true);  

 }
```

Works well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to answer my own post, but I changed the program completely.
I do not know if I can remove the code from the first post. So I put in a new post.

I changed a application but still have a problem with entering the array to another method.
Copy arrays by "Arrays.copyOf b = (a, a.length)" and changing the array as static does not fix a problem.
I can't enter array from setSignal() to getSignal() in OscilloscopeController class.

**OscilloscopeController.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class OscilloscopeController {

private static int frameSize = (int) (44100 / 100F);
private int idx, numFramesToSkip = 10;
private static int[] toDraw = new int[frameSize];
private static int[] data = new int[frameSize];

public OscilloscopeController() {

    for (int i = 0; i < frameSize; i++) {
        toDraw[i] = 0;
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}

public void setSignal(int in) {
     // Because the Model layer is off, I generate a test signal
   Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 44100; i++) {
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(32675 * 2) - (32675);
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            j = randomInt;
        }
     in = j;
    }


    if (idx++ > frameSize * numFramesToSkip) 
    { 
        idx = 0;
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (idx < frameSize) {
            data[idx] = in;
        }

        if (idx == frameSize) 
        {   
            // HERE IS PROBLEM. I'D LIKE THIS toDraw in getSignal()
            toDraw = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
        }
    }
}

public int[] getSignal() {


    // IF UNCOMMENT BELOW WORKS FINE, OTHERWISE ZERO VALUES
    /*
         Random randomGenerator = new Random();
         int j=0;
         for (int i = 0; i < 440; i++) {
         int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(32675*2)-(32675);
         if (i%4==0) j = randomInt;
         toDraw[i]=j; 
    }
    */

for (int i = 0; i < frameSize; i++) 
        System.out.println("Controller.getSignal() = "+ toDraw[i]);

        return toDraw;
    }
}
```

**MainPanel** contains main method:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel());
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
     }
    });
   }

private final OscilloscopeView oscView = new OscilloscopeView();
private final OscilloscopeController oscController = new OscilloscopeController();

 public MainPanel() {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

    // a lot of other components here

    oscView.setData(oscController.getSignal());
    add(oscView);
  }
}
```

**OscilloscopeView.java**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class OscilloscopeView extends JPanel {

    private  OscPlotter plotter  = new OscPlotter(441);;

    public OscilloscopeView()
    {
        setSize(320,210);
        add(this.plotter);
    }

    public void setData(int[] data){
    plotter.setData(data);  
    }  
}
```

**OscPlotter.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class OscPlotter extends JPanel{


    private int width = 320;
    private int height = 130;
    private float widthC;
    private float heightC;
    private int sampleSize;
    private int frameSize;
    private  int[] toDraw;
    private float x,prevX;

    public OscPlotter(int fSize){
        setSize(width,height);      
        setPreferredSize(this.getSize());
        this.frameSize = fSize;
        this.toDraw =  new int[441];
        sampleSize = 1;

    } 


    public void setData(int[] data){
        toDraw = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
        repaint();
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 

        widthC = ((float)width/frameSize);          
        sampleSize = (16 == 16 ? 65536 : 256);          
        heightC = (((float)height-15)/sampleSize);          

        g.setColor(Color.black);            
        g.fillRect(0,0,width,height);  

        g.setColor(Color.gray);     
        for (int i = 1; i<height;i+=height/8) 
            g.drawLine(0,i,width,i);            
        for (int i = 1; i<width;i+=width/8) 
            g.drawLine(i,0,i,height);       

        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        g.drawLine(0,(int)(height/2),width,(int)((height/2)));


        g.setColor(Color.green);        
        x = 0;      

        for (int i = 0; i< frameSize-1;i++)
        { 
            prevX = x;
            x +=widthC;
            // draw the read waveform data
            g.drawLine ((int)prevX,(int)((height/2+toDraw[i]*heightC)),(int)x,(int)((height/2+toDraw[i+1]*heightC))); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by " I can't enter array from setSignal() to getSignal() in OscilloscopeController class." ?where do you actually call setSignal() ?

Comment: The problem was a lack of communication OscilloscopeView to OscilloscopeConroller.. I solved the problem using a static factory method. Thanks for tips.